# Should I be building GUI applications on Windows using Perl & Tk?

Tags: perl, user-interface

I have a bunch of related Perl scripts that I would like to put together in one convenient place.  So I was thinking of building a GUI and incorporating the scripts.  I'm using Strawberry Perl on Windows XP and have just installed Tk from cpan about fifteen minutes ago.  Before I go for it, I want some sound advice either for or against it.

My other option is to translate the Perl scripts into VB and use Visual Studio 2008, but that might be too much hassle for an outcome that might end up all the same had I just stuck with Perl & Tk.

I haven't looked yet, but maybe there is a module for Visual Studio that would allow me to invoke Perl scripts?

The main requirements are:

- It must be able to communicate with MySQL
- It must be able to fetch & parse XML files from the internet
- It must be transportable, scalable, and sustainable

What direction would you take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've built Perl/Tk apps on Windows before and found it just fine, including using [PAR](http://par.perl.org/) to package everything up for distribution to others.  It was nice being able to do most of my development on a proper Linux system and have things just magically work on Windows :)  The only gotcha I encountered is that Tk doesn't play well with ithreads.

Answer (score 3):

I personally would recommend [wxPerl](http://wxperl.sourceforge.net/) over Tk. It has native looking widgets, at least in my view leads to cleaner code and you can use [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/) as a GUI designer.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't programmed with Perl/Tk I would think that Tkx (developed by Activestate) would be a better option. Tkx is a thin layer over Tcl/Tk, which gives it access to the new themed widgets in Tcl/Tk so your application would look better.

Perl/Tk has a lot more documentation around, but the module itself does not seem to be developed anymore. The documentation for Tkx is very sparse but by following the Tkx tutorial files on CPAN, it should be easy to get started.

WxWidgets (available for Perl via wxPerl) is an excellent graphical toolkit, but wxPerl only implements a subset of the available widgets.

PAR is convenient but if you go with Perl/Tk, the result will not run natively on OS X. (Users will need to run X11 first, which is problematic, especially with more recent version of OS X). If you go with Tkx, you can get native application on Mac OSX. Also, ActiveStates's PDK gives you a simple way to package everything to deploy to Windows, Linux, and OS X.

For reference, see the the software (AntConc and AntWordProfiler) at the following site http://www.antlab.sci.waseda.ac.jp/software.html, where AntConc was developed using Perl/Tk and AntWordProfiler was developed using Tkx.

Answer (score 0):

The [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_methods.aspx) class allows to start new processes from a C# (WPF/Winforms) frontend.
I guess that way you can keep your Perl scripts and use the nice Visual Studio GUI builder.